# Clicking an applications menu bar item with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I use [Time Tracker For Mac](https://code.google.com/p/time-tracker-mac/) as my, well, time tracker. It has a menu bar item which I want to be able to access via keyboard shortcut.

I found a way to click the item with GUI scripting:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
    click menu bar item of menu bar 2
end tell
```

Unfortunately the script does not return success unless I acted on the menu (i.e. pressing Enter or Esc key). So if I want to trigger the down arrow key...

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
    click menu bar item of menu bar 2
    -- hangs here forever until menu is closed
    tell application "System Events" to key code 124
end tell
```

the script just waits forever. If I hit escape the menu bar item closes and only then the down arrow key will be triggered.

It's kind weird. I just need the menu bar item's click to *not* block further script execution.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The click command returns after about 5 seconds for me. One workaround is to use ignoring application responses and terminate System Events:

```
ignoring application responses
    tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
        click menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end ignoring
do shell script "killall System\\ Events"
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
    tell menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
        click menu item 2 of menu 1
    end tell
end tell
```

Related questions:

- [Applescript: on clicking Menu Bar item via gui script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492839)
- [Is AppleScript UI Scripting very slow in general, or is it my script, or something else?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365281)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This works indeed. I'm not very comfortable to entirely kill the process, but I will try this for a while.

Comment: According to [Daemons and Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Lifecycle.html), loginwindow sends TERM or KILL signals to background processes and daemons at logout. System Events supports sudden termination, so it should be safe to even send it a KILL signal.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the key code for the down arrow seems to be 125. Try this:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Time Tracker"
    click menu bar item of menu bar 2
    key code 125
    key code 36
end tell
```

There is a short delay (a couple of seconds) after the click menu bar... command, I don't know why.